# Phonegap doesn't support sql Rand(), what to do?

Tags: sqlite, random, cordova

Is there an alternative for this?

This is my code

```
function loadQ() {
   db.transaction(function(t) {
     t.executeSql('SELECT * FROM q ORDER BY RAND()', [], qDataHandler, errorHandler);
   });
};
```

Now, this doesn't work.  It works if I remove the Rand() and replace it with LIMIT 1.  But I want the result to be randomized.

I am thinking of running a query for a total rows and then create a function that picks numbers from 0 to total rows and then use the result in my loadQ as ID.  But i think this is a tedious work.  Am wondering if you have any better ideas for this?

many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the random value as the PK, it'll fail if you have gaps in your rows.

Here's a better solution:

1. Query for a COUNT() of rows.
2. Generate a random number from 0 to the count
3. Use the result in `LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?`